# How can I get the biggest value?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Here is my table:

```
-- log
+----+---------+------------+
| id | user_id |    seen    |
+----+---------+------------+
| 1  | 2342    | 1442664886 |
| 2  | 3244    | 1442665851 |
| 3  | 2342    | 1442711823 |
| 4  | 7654    | 1442864219 |
| 5  | 3244    | 1442954080 |
| 6  | 9984    | 1442984716 |
+----+---------+------------+
```

I want to get the biggest seen time for a specific user as *last seen*. I can do that by these two queries:

**First query:**

```
SELECT seen AS last_seen
FROM log
WHERE user_id = :id
ORDER BY seen DESC
LIMIT 1
```

**Second query:**

```
SELECT MAX(seen) AS last_seen
FROM log
WHERE user_id = :id
```

Well which one is the standard way? Should I go with which one? Is there any different in the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both fine.  Both will take advantage of an index on `log(user_id, seen)`.

The first is often preferable because you can pull in the whole row and get information from other columns.

Comment: not OP , but if you let me ask , `ORDER BY seen DESC` would the ordering operation take more time than finding the max value ?

Comment: @Ali see the duplicate topic for a detailed answer.